# ASP MVC Net using Check list kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to get data from kendogrid2 and set it to kendogrid1?

I have the 2 kendogrid using checklist grid.

This is the jquery code:

```
 $("#btnAddPortfolio").click(function () {
            var grid2 = $("#portfolioGrid2").data("kendoGrid");
            var dt = grid2.dataItem

            var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: [{ "Portfolio": "Data of checklist selected item"}]
                });

            $("#portfolioGrid1").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(ds);
            $('#grid2_modal').modal('toggle');  
        });
```

How to get the value of selected item on `#portofolioGrid2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve it:

```
$("#grid1").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: [{ Name: "John Doe" }, { Name: "Jane Doe" }, 
        { Name: "Doe John" }, { Name: "Doe Jane" }]
    },
    columns: [{
        template: '<input type="checkbox" />',
        width: 40
    }, {
        field: "Name"
    }]
});

$("#grid2").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "Name"
    }]
});

$("#transfer-items").on("click", function() {
    let grid1 = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid"),
        grid2 = $("#grid2").data("kendoGrid"),
        $checkboxes = grid1.tbody.find('input:checked').toArray();

    if ($checkboxes.length) {
        $checkboxes.forEach($chk => {
            let item = grid1.dataItem($chk.closest("tr"));
            grid2.dataSource.add(item);
        });
    }
    else {
        window.alert("No item has been selected.");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UXIPu)